# Select the html in an 'a' tag with jquery but getting html is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting:

> `this.html()` is not a function?

```
$('a[href*="section"]').click(function() {
    var texthtml = this.html();                    
    $(document).find("div.SectionExpandable__title:contains("+texthtml+")").click();
});
```

How do I get the html from an `a` tag so I can pass it to the next part of the code?

Comment: maybe try `$(this).html()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `this`, you can call DOM methods on it, but not jQuery methods. When using `$(this)`, you can call jQuery methods on it, but not DOM methods.

and `html()` is jQuery method, so :

Change :

```
this.html();
```

To :

```
$(this).html();
```

Comment: ha ha  @ehsan - already posted that - its a race with these answers :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to reference the jquery element via $(this)

```
$('a[href*="section"]').click(function() {
    var texthtml = $(this).html();                    
    $(document).find("div.SectionExpandable__title:contains("+texthtml+")").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*="section"]').click(function() {
    var texthtml = jQuery(this).html();
    $(document).find("div.SectionExpandable__title:contains("+texthtml +")").click();
});
```